# Crossfilter / dc.table sorting by Timestamp

Tags: dc.js

I want to sort my table by the timestamp descending but in this field my testcases ascending.

How can I do the oposite?
I hope i can explain my problem.

```
  //------------------------table------------------------------------
    var TestCaseDim2 = perfData.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.TestCase;
    });
  
    dc.dataTable('#data-table')
    .dimension(TestCaseDim2)
        .group(function (d) {
            return d.Timestamp.bold().fontcolor("darkblue");
        })
    .columns([

        function (d) { return d.SerialNumber;},  
        function (d) { return d.Result;},
        ])
        .width(get2ndWindowSize())
        .order(d3.descending )
        .size(700)
        .renderlet(function (table) {
        table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
        });
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: can you maybe help me ? :/ @Ethan Jewett

Comment: Have you asked/searched on the dc.js mailing list? I think there have been discussions about this. There is not an easy way to control sorting of groups and rows separately that I am aware of. If you put together a working example I can try to help. This JSFiddle has the necessary libraries included: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/jusjkm8j/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tetut91e/26/ This is my js fiddle... The Sorting of the Timestamp is right ( Newest is on the top)  but the Testscript's are not 
alphabetical :/ Do you know what i mean . If i'm using .order(d3.descending ) then the text is alphabetical (perfect) , but the oldest TimeStamp is on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle example, I believe but am not sure that within your groups your test scripts are ordered by test case because that is the dimension you have used on your data table.

The real issue is that in a dc.js data table, you can't control the order of groups and the ordering within groups separately. The ordering within groups is based on the order returned by the dimension and the order of groups is determined by the text of the group. Both are either ascending or descending depending on what you set in `dataTable.order`.

So, what do we do? I'd recommend defining your dimension on the property you want to sort by within the groups, and then if necessary reversing the direction of the dimension sort by flipping the top/bottom functions on the dimension:

```
var perfData = crossfilter(data);
var testScriptDim = perfData.dimension(function (d) {
  return d.testscript;
});
testScriptDim.top = testScriptDim.bottom;

dc.dataTable('#data-table')
  .dimension(testScriptDim)
    .group(function (d) {
      return d.date.bold().fontcolor("darkblue");
    })
    .columns([
      function (d) { return d.testscript; },
      function (d) { return d.duration; },
      function (d) { return d.clickcount; }
    ])
    .size(100) 
    .order(d3.descending)
    .renderlet(function (table) {
      table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
    });
```

Here's an updated version of your JSFiddle that I think does what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/xzrp0ggv/1/